# Saving SMS from android into phpmyadmin database

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app that will save incoming text messages in a MySQL database on a remote server. What is the best way to do this? What components do I need to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

via posting :)

```
private void postSms(String text) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
        url = new URL("http://yourserver.com/sendsms");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sms", text));//POST param as "sms"

        OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getQuery(params));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        String status = new String(Streams.getBytes(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        Log.d(TAG, new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName() + ":insert status=" + status);

    } catch (MalformedURLException | ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Don't forget add this to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Or read it on my [blog](http://blog.mokrzycki.io/?p=182#more-182)

Comment: You are a very patient man. Kudos to you. I am flagging this question as low quality.

Comment: He also needs a PHP component to receive the incoming post, that stores it in the database.

Comment: @GlennBech, thanks man, but the question was about android - so the answer was straight

Comment: I can strongly recommend using the Square Retrofit library for REST communication in Android. It hides a lot of the nitty gritty details of the HTTP protocol https://github.com/square/retrofit

Comment: hi sir @deadfish im so new at this coding can you give me a clue on coding the php?